# how to stop android emulator from automatically turning off

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using the SDK provided from the android developers website. My android emulator seems to turn off automatically after some period of inactivity. I need to press the power hardware button provided next to the emulator screen to be able to run applications again. The problem is that I don't know what enabled this feature. This doesn't happen in the other computers where I have installed the SDK. The only difference in this computer's installation is that I had updated the SDK to include Android 4.3 APIs.

How do I stop the emulator from automatically turning off?

---EDIT---
Create new AVD screen in the SDK
[image]

Answer (score 20):

I have this problem because I changed the Charger Connection to none under the Battery menu of the emulator. Turning it back to AC Charger stopped the screen being turned off.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

In your `emulator` go to `Settings ->  Display -> Sleep`, change to 30 minutes.

Comment: Still sleeping after this change.

Answer (score 9):

Go into "Developer options" in Android Settings and turn on the option "Stay awake - Screen will never sleep while charging". I don't remember ever having to do this before on my emulators, but with the latest one I created I did.

Comment: Yes, so annoying. My emulator used to turn its screen off about every 30 seconds

Comment: Still sleeping after a while.

Comment: @DavoudBadamchi also check the answer from Lavish Garg about charger connection, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61267525)

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem because I changed the Charger Connection to none under the Battery menu of the emulator. Turning it back to AC Charger stopped the screen being turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on a Sleep|Hibernate|Powerdown setting on that AVD's settings, or perhaps are they are set on your AVD by default to powerdown?
It would persist everytime you start that AVD, unless you tell the AVD Manager to wipe all previous settings every time it launches.

You might try recreating a new AVD instance and deleting the current one.

***EDIT: New Pictures ****
Now that you set up an AVD, and went inside the emulator to turn off|delay the "sleep|suspend" mode, you need to make sure the AVD manager never overwrites this setting when you start that AVD the next time.

From the AVD manager, if you click start, it will show you this dialog, make shure "wipe user data" is unchecked.

[image: Launch Options Dialog]

And to make sure the Eclipse isn't wiping out your AVD settings when you launch an emulator with the "Run As Andriod Application" or similar commands, you must make sure your run configurations are not set to wipe user data either:
Run menu==>Run Configurations...

[image: Wipe User Data checkbox on Run Configurations Window]

Of course, the very first time you set up an AVD & emulate it, you'll have to go into its settings menus and change it to suit you.

Comment: I cannot find how to apply those settings when creating a new AVD; for now I have fixed this going to the emulated phone's display settings, and setting it to go to sleep after an inactivity of 30 mins, which was set to 10 sec by default, but i would like to turn this feature off permanently if i can

Comment: I have added my New AVD window to the question

Answer (score 0):

There are device / emulator settings that do this. It seems they vary with the model. On my Nexus Nougat emulator, there are 2 of them: first, set battery / battery saver off (this is a setting that only affects the device while it's charging). Then you need to give a big value to display / sleep, like 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by the following step:

Please ensure "Windows Hypervisor Platform" is installed. If it's not installed, install it, restart your computer and you will be good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. Surely one of the most important things to do is this one below:

- go to your android simulator device, go to Settings icon inside the emulator apps, then click on battery and change Sleep time to 30 minutes